# images inside webview are getting blurred on touch

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I am using a webview inside fragment and loading html page from assets folder. My issue is when I scroll the page all images are getting blurred?

After putting some logs this is happening onTouch of webview. I am not getting how do I stop it.

I have checked it in 4.0 and 2.3 it is happening only in ICS.

Comment: @ Ankit have you found the solution of this. my app have same problem ?

Comment: some workaround I have done. I will post it here as answer.

Comment: Yes please paste it. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure what line of my code did it but it is working now

```
             mWebView.clearFocus();
         mWebView.setFocusable(false);
         mWebView.setSelected(false);
         mWebView.callOnClick();
         mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(false);
         mWebView.setOnTouchListener(null);
         mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

I have put this code in `onCreateView` of my fragment. `mWebView` is webview in my view.